# Magento out of memory when switching currency and items in cart

Tags: mysql, magento

Scenario
    have an empty cart
    switch to euros
    Loads fine
    Add a product to cart
    Loads fine
    Switch back to pounds
    Site hangs and then crashes
    Site cant be reloaded until all cookies are deleted

I can see in the mysql.log that same queries are in an infite loop. I have magento enterprise 1.14 on my site.

Really appericiate if I could get some help here. I find people with similiar problems but none of the solutions are working.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out what is triggering the issue.

To do that, please disable all extensions you have installed on your store, and then enable them one by one trying to reproduce the issue.

If that doesn't work, please increase the value of the variables memory_limit, max_execution_time.

Let us know if it helps.